# OrderBy to alternate between the start and end of a list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a list {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11}

I want to go through the list using code like

```
foreach (int myInt in myIntList.OrderBy(...))
{
    /// Do stuff
}
```

But the order here would be 1 then 11 then 3 then 9 then 5 then 7. How would I do this with order by etc?

My actual case is slightly more complicated with the for loop looking like this:

```
foreach (Tuple<string, int, int, int> im in iconMappings.OrderBy(i => i.Item4).ThenByDescending(i => i.Item3))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

So having ordered them like above I THEN need to get the alternating elements, so would ideally like an answer that can be applied to this.

Comment: _"But the order here would be 1 then 11 then 3 then 9 then 5 then 7"_ Does that mean that this is your desired result?

Comment: Yes, effectively in generic terms the desired order for n items is 1st then nth then 2nd then (n-1)th then 3rd etc

Comment: @Knightsy `OrderBy` isn't required, simply do a `for` loop and manipulate the index each time. Although this assumes an already-ordered set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This gives the order you want:

```
List<int> myIntList = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 });

var result = myIntList
    .Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i })
    .OrderBy(v => Math.Min(v.Index, Math.Abs((myIntList .Count - 1) - v.Index)))
    .Select(v => v.Value);
```

---

```
foreach (var v in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
}
```

Gives:

```
1
11
3
9
5
7
```

Comment: where is x coming from in x.Count?

Comment: @Knightsy A typo, sorry - fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
IEnumerable<int> alternatingOrder = intList
    .Select((i, index) => new
    {
        i,
        Margin = index < intList.Count / 2 ? index : intList.Count - ++index
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Margin)
    .Select(x => x.i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordering follows a pattern, depending on the item, your ordering logic exists out of match the first and last, match the second and the one before last and so on. => 1, n, 2, n-1, ... 
So basically you will have to loop through the list =>

```
var myNewList = new List<...>();
foreach(int i = 0, i < myItems.Count, i++)
{
myNewList.add(myItems.First());
myNewList.add(myItems.Last());
myItems.Remove(myItems.First());
myItems.Remove(myItems.Last();
}
```

Comment: You also need to check if there's more than 1 element left in every iteration, because your first and last item would be the same and Remove() method would explode.

Comment: Indeed, the above is pseudo code, untested and doesn't guarantee success, but it does give you an idea on how to work your problem.

Answer (score 1):

A re-usable tic-tac method for a set of any items (not just `int`) could be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var numbers = new[] {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13};

        foreach (var num in numbers.TicTac())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(num);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TicTac<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var count = source.Count();

        var leftIterator = source.GetEnumerator();
        var rightIterator = source.Reverse().GetEnumerator();

        int returned = 0;
        bool right = false;

        while (returned < count)
        {
            if (right)
            {
                rightIterator.MoveNext();
                yield return rightIterator.Current;
            }
            else
            {
                leftIterator.MoveNext();
                yield return leftIterator.Current;
            }

            returned++;
            right = !right;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you either assume the array is already ordered, or you order it prior to calling.

Then you can optimise it to understand what `source` is, such as providing a better implementation if `source` is a `T[]`, or an `IList<T>` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Another option by *not using OrderBy, but custom enumerator*. (I omitted bounds checking and other stuff for sake of example)

```
public  IEnumerable<int> GetNext(List<int> data) 
{       
      int leftIndex = 0; 
      int rightIndex = data.Count() -1; 
      while(leftIndex < rightIndex) 
      {
         yield return data[leftIndex++];        
         yield return data[rightIndex--];       

      }
}
```

use this like

```
foreach(var a in GetNext(list)){...}
```

Benefits of this are that

> 1) you don't alter oringinal array
>   2)  you don't create a copy of data 
>   in memory (which may be harmful in case of big arrays)

you just roll over the data you already have in just some specific way.